# .So file for FFMPEG from NDK

Tags: android, ffmpeg, native, shared-libraries, android-ndk-r5

I am not able to make .So file for FFMPEG from NDK .
I Just Download a zip file from GitHub 
https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg
Then i used CYGWIN for using NDK commends for making .so file from jni folder in ffmpeg library then on Cygwin  i am giving path of ffmpeg up to jni folder then 
$ ndk build
after some process error message came

```
  C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\AndroidFFmpeg-master\AndroidFFmpeg-master\FFmpegLibrary
 \jni>ndk-build
 Android NDK: ERROR:C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/AndroidFFmpeg-master/AndroidFFmpeg-m
  aster/FFmpegLibrary//jni/Android.mk:ffmpeg-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a
  missing file
  Android NDK: Check that C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/AndroidFFmpeg-master/AndroidFFm
  peg-master/FFmpegLibrary//jni/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so exists  or t
  hat its path is correct
  D:/NDK/androidndk/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting
 .  Stop.
```

Any type of help is Appricated.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [this fork](https://github.com/matthewn4444/VPlayer_lib) from AppUnite's AndroidFFmpeg. Much clearer build instruction. I've successfully built FFmpeg v3.0.2 using NDK 11c.

Another piece of advice, do the build on Ubuntu, it will save you a lot of brain cells. After you've successfully built it on Ubuntu you can copy the whole thing and use it on Windows.

See my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/0a4e48f903bf9b99a7bd7fbb61a206eb) for some errors you may encounter.